Showing that term involving the sequence of prime numbers converges
A necessary condition for a sequence $(a_n)$ to be Benford-distributed is that
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}n \log_{10}\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right)=\infty$$
has to hold.
Consider the sequence of prime numbers that is NOT Benford-distributed. This is what I've tried to show this:
According to the prime number theorem $p_n\sim n \ln(n)$. Then: $n \log\left(\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n}\right)\sim n \log\left(\frac{(n+1)\ln(n+1)}{n\ln(n)}\right):=nL$
With the Taylor expansion of $L$ at $n=\infty$ we get: $L\approx\frac{\ln(n)+1}{n\ln(10)\ln(n)}$
So: $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} nL=\frac{1}{\ln(10)}\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(n)+1}{\ln(n)}=\frac{1}{\ln(10)} \neq \infty$$
My prof said this proof is not accurate enough and he's not whether it's correct.
How can I show this?
Thanks!
